# Fixing the connection on ACCOR PUSHON® R-SERIES Supply Stop Valve

Tags: valve

I'm still learning since I just bought a house not long ago. I appreciate any help here for the disconnected valve under my sink.
[image: This is the ACCOR PUSHON® R-SERIES Supply Stop Valve]

Filtered water is supposed to go through this valve to the fridge(I know fridge has anther filter built in but this is how it's set up when I bought the house). But one day, the tube connecting this valve popped out and water everywhere. It was terrible.

It is not as easy as it looks to re-connect the tube with the pushon valve. It does not fit in the inlet of the valve(how was it working?). I could see one end of the tube was squeezed to do that but I just cant. Even if I could, how do I make sure it's fastened and won't pop out again?

[image: Other parts]

Comment: I suspect you'll need to buy a new connector.  Usually these connectors have compressible washers betweenthe brass nut and the internal stop, and those aren't reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tube that connects the connector and the pushon valve" in your picture looks like soft clear vinyl tubing; if it is, that was the cause of the failure.

Your valve has a compression type connection:

[image]

and is designed for tubing (copper or poly/plastic) that is fairly rigid rather than soft. The connection utilizes a ferrule:

[image]

which I do not see any sign or mention of in your pictures or question. You will likely need to replace that short piece of tubing with a section of tubing that is compatible with both the connector and the valve's compression fitting, like poly tubing:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I do not see a compression ring or ferrule installed. It seems to me that I need it in addition to the poly tubing.